# CSS Gradient live refresh

Tags: html, css

This is a little nitpicky, but if it is avoidable I am hoping someone might have a solution. I have a page that I want to use css gradient for the background. This page has a fixed header at the top that content needs to scroll behind, but I want to continue the background gradient for the header. But when coded, if I resize the page it doesn't refresh the gradient, and creates banding.

The code looks like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
  <style>
    body{padding: 0;margin:0;}
        
    .back{width:100vw;height:100vh;background: radial-gradient(ellipse,#fff  0%, #000 100%);overflow: hidden;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index: -1}
        
    .top{width: 100vw;height: 11.5vw;background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 50vh,#fff  0%, #000 100%); position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 10}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="back"></div>
  <div class="top"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And produces this:
[Working gradient example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3edN.jpg)

But when I resize the page, it will do something like this:
[broken gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzsmT.jpg)

Until I refresh the page, it will remain broken. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is `div.top` your "header"?

Comment: while jalpesh's answer feels a bit like a cop-out, it does beg the question- why are you duplicating the background logic on the top bar at all? why not let the top bar have a transparent background? Also, I can reproduce the issue, but interestingly, whenever I toggle the devtools, it "fixes itself". Who knows- it might be a bug.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I am duping the bg because the header is fixed at the top of the viewport and needs to be in front of the page content as it scrolls, while the background obviously needs to be behind the content. I want the whole viewport to appear as a seamless gradient, but I also need these layers to function as such. jalpesh's answer is a copout that does not remedy the issue. Like I said it is nitpicky, it also corrects itself for me if I maximize/ window the browser, and in the actual use, there is a shadow under the header that hides differences. Mostly I am just curious.

Answer (score -1):

simply remove "background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 50vh, #fff 0%, #000 100%);" this line from ".top" class

like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .back {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background: radial-gradient(ellipse, #fff 0%, #000 100%);
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
      }

      .top {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 11.5vw;
        /* c */
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. If `div.top` is in fact the "header" that OP mentioned, this is the solution. However, OP hasn't confirmed this as of yet.

Comment: This does not remedy the issue. As I said in the original Q in the actual page there will be scrollable content between div.top and div.back so making div.top transparent wouldn't mask the page content. In the actual page there are nav buttons and a logo etc in the header that I don't want content visible behind, but I want the whole viewport to look like a single seamless gradient behind header and page content. Thanks for the suggestion!